# each finite group with abelian chain induces cyclic chain

Tags: abstract-algebra

Show that every finite group with abelian chain induces also a cyclic chain.

I am sorry, dear mathematicians but for this task it really lacks ideas.

I would be very happy to get a hint for you and what they mean by this task.:-)

EDIT: 
An abelian chain in a gruop $G$ is a chain of subgroups $G_0\subset G_1\subset \ldots G_k=G$ such that $G_i\subset G_{i+1}$ is normal and $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is abelian (or cyclic) for all $i$ (in the contrast to solvable groups $G_0$ doesn't have to be the trivial group)

Comment: Can you at least right the definition? What do you mean by abelian chain?

Comment: yeah, sry, I edited it now.

Comment: Since you mention solvable groups, are you familiar with the argument for those? The same one applies here.

Comment: Since $G_{i+1}/G_i$ is abelian it can be factorized as dircet product of cyclic groups. From here, use the correspondece theorem to refine your chain by refinig each $G_{i+1}/G_i$.